# Device Detection Using CSS Media Queries and Flask/Jinja

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to use CSS media queries with Jinja and Flask to determine device type and serve appropriately sized images based on the device.  Requests from mobile phones would get smaller images than desktops, tablets, etc.

The problem is that `{{ post|get_image(post, 480) }}` gets evaluated independent of the media query thus triggering the `get_image` custom template filter for each instance.  `get_image` is also where the correct image is rendered for the device, so multiple, perhaps unnecessary, calls can negatively effect performance.

Ideally, only one media query is enacted with one call to `get_image`, but the challenge is that the media query and Jinja are completely independent of each other in that one knows nothing about the other.

I'd really appreciate alternative approaches or suggestions to improve my approach.  Thanks in advance!

Here's an example of the media queries:

```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .post {
      background: url("{{ post|get_image(post, 480) }}") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1224px) {
    .post {
      background: url("{{ post|get_image(post, 1224) }}") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're asking for ways to "improve" this, but as far as I'm concerned, there is no issue with what you're doing. What are you really concerned about? Do you think that the template will render too slowly with multiple calls to `get_image`?

Comment: Yes, there could be 4-5 calls to get_image (one for each media query) which is what actually generates the appropriate image.

Comment: Is there any way you could have `get_image` _not_ generate the image?

Comment: I need to tie image generation to device type.  Any suggestions on how  or where I may do this?

Comment: No, you can't duplicate what you have above without tradeoffs. For example, the HTTP response with the background URL is sent once. If you change this so that the user gets only one background URL for their current screen size, and the user resizes their screen, they are stuck with the image you gave them (whereas a media query would switch to the new image). I'm not sure if you really need to generate the image during the GET request of this CSS, or you just think you do. Why not generate the image the first time the image URL is accessed, then cache it?

Comment: If I create and cache multiple images ahead of time I may unnecessarily be generating and storing images that never get used.  Doing it at runtime based on media queries at least only generates and caches what's being required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your setup to be something like this:

```
.post {
    background: none no-repeat center center fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .post {
      background-image: url("{{ get_image_url(post, 480) }}"); 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1224px) {
    .post {
      background-image: url("{{ get_image_url(post, 1224) }}"); 
    }
}
```

The URLs you are generating might look something like this:

```
/posts/<int:post_id>/background?s=NNNN
```

Then, set up your proxy server to serve such images out of a cache directory and to forward them on to your image generation controller if the image does not exist:

```
# Fake server configuration
# for no server known to man
location /posts/(:post-id:\d+)/background {
    try_files /cache/:post-id:_\d+\.png or @flask-server  
}
```

Finally, in your Flask controller generate the image, save it to your cache directory, and serve it back to the requester:

```
@app.route("/posts/<int:post_id>/background")
def generate_image(post_id):
    # Assume that if we got here the image does not yet exist
    dimensions = int(request.args.get("s", 800), 10)

    image_data = generate_image(post_id, dimensions)

    image_name = "{}_{}.png".format(post_id, dimensions)
    image_path = os.path.join("/cache", image_name)

    with open(image_path, "wb") as image:
        image.write(image_data)

    return Response(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

If the image generation part is too expensive to even contemplate doing in the controller you can instead return 204 No-Content with Cache-Control set to private and Expires set in the past and put the image generation task into an out-of-process queue.  Then just poll that endpoint in your JavaScript code until the image is ready to be served by your proxy server.

Comment: In your example won't get_image_url() get called multiple times when the template is rendered?

Comment: @Raj - yes, but it is just generating a string, not building the actual image.  The image generation is deferred until request time, when the browser will (theoretically) ask for only the image it actually needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I didn't end up implementing this precisely, but I did use this general pattern so it was super helpful.  So I am marking this as the correct answer!  Thanks again!